# Set HSTS header in htaccess if already isn't present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hsts

I've set HSTS in a common .htaccess which is being used by multiple sites.

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

But when a site has already set HSTS header from the virtual host configuration, then there happens to be two HSTS header added to the response.

So before I set HSTS on .htaccess, how do I check if an HSTS header is already present?

Answer (score 2):

It's ok with `Header set`. There would be a problem if you had used `Header add`.

> **add**
>       : The response header is added to the existing set of headers, even if this header already exists. This can result in two (or more)
>   headers having the same name. This can lead to unforeseen
>   consequences, and in general set, append or merge should be used
>   instead.
>
> **set**
>       : The response header is set, replacing any previous header with this name. The value may be a format string.
>
> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_headers.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use setifempty

```
Header always setifempty Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

Comment: Thanks - but `SetIfEmpty available in 2.4.7 and later, expr=value available in 2.4.10 and later`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Croises reported, it should by default just overwrite but in my case, it turns out the header set by the virtual host configs were using the `always` keyword hence the header set by .htaccess was also added.

You could also use `setifempty` but in my case my Apache wasn't the latest (only supported for 2.4.7 onwards) 
So I had to do like below to make it work.

```
Header always unset Strict-Transport-Security
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```